# Why didn't the Jews of Persia leave after Haman's decree?

Tags: history, megillat-esther, haman, persia

After Haman's genocidal edict was sent out to all the people of the Persian kingdom why was there not a mass exodus of Jews to parts of the world not under the dominion of Achashveirosh and his law?

Comment: The megilla gives the impression that a large part of the world was under Persian control at that point and it may not have been practical for everyone to leave.  Bear in mind that travel time was far greater in those days, and we don't know what kind of political, legal and bureaucratic restrictions there would have been.   They may not have known where they could get to safely as well. Some may have also not believed that it would really happen, or thought they would be no better off elsewhere.  It may be worth reading up on why many Jews didn't flee the Nazis as likely a lot of commonality.

Answer (score 4):

The first decrees went out on Nissan 13 3404, and they were a forewarning to a destruction one year in advance.

The people's first response was to fast, as well as mourn, weep, wear sackcloth, ashes and lament (Ya'arot Devash), and this took place starting the next day, Nissan 14.

It lasted 3 days and from it Hashem accepted their teshuva (Megilla 12a). Immediately after this was complete, Haman was executed. Within a few months, the decree was officially reversed (Sivan 23) and a counter-decree was sent.

Therefore it is conceivable that nobody ran away because the whole thing was over very quickly. It wasn't "completely over" until Adar 13 3405, but the danger was effectively over and it was merely a concern that some people might go against the new orders and kill anyway. I doubt that was the kind of mortal danger that would compel people to run away, as the original decree might have been.

Also note that there is plenty in the sources that the Jews fully accepted that this decree was from heaven and not a mortal "happening". They would have realised that running away would have done no good in the face of a decree from heaven. Instead they focussed on teshuva, as mentioned.

Comment: @RabbiKaii just because the decree was from heaven, doesn't mean that there is no point in running away!  I'm sure that Hashem doesn't just want us to stand there and get killed if we have a chance to escape!

Comment: That's a very modern way of thinking @MosesSupposes. Our illustrious ancestors were much more in tune with the notion that only sin brings about suffering.

Comment: That wasn't my point - we don't know if the decree from heaven is that we are supposed to be killed or be dislodged from our home and be forced to flee or have a terrifying experience or something else.  Yes, of course we should do teshuva etc, but we also have an obligation to save ourselves through practical means!

Comment: @MosesSupposes this was at the time of the prophets. The "hishtadlus" that people did back then would always be to do with their relationship with Hashem. Jonah thought he could escape his mission by following Hashem's rules and go outside EY, which would exempt him. When he got caught on the boat, he didn't make any hishtadlus "row harder!", but rather said what can I do, throw me in the water. Many stories like this in Tanach and aggadata. It's very modern to make a big point about "practical hishtadlus". Where that fits in is discussed in Shaar Habitachon very well.

Comment: Yonah is not a good example - he was going against Hashem's instruction!  I don't agree it is a modern thing.  Counterexamples off the top of my head: Yaakov split his camp 3 ways before meeting Esav.  Moshe fled Mitzrayim.

Comment: @MosesSupposes Yonah is a great example because even when going against Hashem's instruction, he was doing it in a way that only took into account his relationship with Hashem. Your two examples were Yaacov and Moshe, both of whom are praised as well as criticised for saying "I am not worthy". Much of the reason these sources bring up that the Jewish people accepted the decree as the fault of their sins was to show their cementing of their relationship with Hashem and trusting Him, and not letting the "Katonti" argument get in the way of that

Comment: My point was that he knew that he was going against Hashem's wishes because Hashem had specifically told him to do something else.  He knew that there was no point in trying to tell them to eg. row harder because by that point he knew that he had done the wrong thing.  So you are saying that the generation of Mordechai was greater than Yaakov Avinu and Moshe Rabbeinu?!

Comment: This will be my last reply but you just proved my point. He _knew_ that running away would be pointless because he had angered Hashem. Many sources say that the people knew they had angered Hashem and brought about this decree. Therefore I posit they probably, especially with all the other points being brought combined, felt that running away would be pointless, or a last resort. The full discussion about what practical hishtadlut needs to be done in these situations is another topic that we won't solve in a comments debate.

Comment: Note however, this Tur, that does bring the point of criticisim against the early tzaddikim that they worried _too much_, and in a way that angered Hashem, that they were not worthy. https://www.sefaria.org/Tur_HaArokh%2C_Genesis.28.20.1?lang=he&with=Translations&lang2=he

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149853/discussion-between-moses-supposes-and-rabbi-kaii).

Answer (score 3):

In Mechilta D'Rashbi, it says:

> אין לך כל אומה ומלכות שנשתעבדה בהן בישראל ולא שלטה מסוף העולם ועד סופו מפני כבודן של ישראל... במלכות מדי הוא אומר... ושם המלך אחשוורוש מס על הארץ ואיי הים
>
> There is no nation or kingdom which enslaved Israel which didn't control the entire world, for the dignity of Israel... By the kingdom of Media it says... "And king Achashverosh placed a tax on the land and on the islands"

(A similar sentiment can be found in the gemara of megilla)

So we see that Achashverosh ruled the entire world. Of course, according to history, this isn't accurate. However, it's possible the meaning is that Achashverosh ruled over the known, or at least civilized, world. Either way, the meaning is pretty clear: the Jews had nowhere to go.

Comment: Since we agree that historically Achashverosh didn't rule the entire world wouldn't that necessitate reading the claim of the mechilta as a guzma/hyperbole?

Comment: @rikitikitembo yes, like I said it could mean that Achashverosh ruled over the known, or civilized, world. Which would both make sense with the pshat and fit history, AFAICT

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting question.

The story of purim takes place 57 years after the destruction of the first beis hamikdash. Jerusalem was decimated and destroyed, even the effort to rebuild the beis hamikdash was halted, by haman and his sons, and signed off by King achashverosh, which seemingly shows that Achashverosh had influence even in jerusalem.

Practically, Achashverosh had dominion over majority of the known world, it doesn't seem like there was an actual place for the jews to flee to - which also shows the magnitude of the decree.