# Examples of practical hishtadlus in Torah/Nevi'im

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach

What examples are there of practical hishtadlus in Torah and Nevi'im?  Two come to my mind immediately - Yaakov Avinu splitting the camp 3 ways before meeting Esav, and Moshe Rabbeinu fleeing Mitzrayim.  Other examples would be appreciated.

In case anyone is interested, it is due to an argument I'm having with Rabbi Kaii on the comments on [his answer on another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138284/2642)

Comment: 1. Avraham hid Sarah in a box, so that she would not be seen by the uncouth Egyptians. 2. Yaakov prepared to wage war with Esav, if necessary. 3. Yaakov hid Dinah from being seen by Esav. 4. Moshe sent spies to spy out the Land of Israel. 5. Yehoshua sent spies to Yericho.

Comment: 6. Yaakov ran away from Esav and didn't rely on a miracle to save him. 7. Yaakov worked long and hard, for many years, for Lavan, even after the 14 years that he needed to work for him for Rachel and Leah. This was as a form of Hishtadlus to earn money.

Comment: 8. David hiding in a cave from Shaul, 9. Shmuel saying he was bringing a korban. I'm not sure collecting counter examples will help because we need to spend more time trying to fully understand each other's points. Mi Yodeya is not for discussion so this hasn't and can't be achieved here. Probably best to take out reference to that and just ask it as its own question

Comment: Kings waging war.

Comment: Yaacov running away from Eisav after the bracha from Yitzchak